# how to get AWS lambda's Logs custom Log Group along with function's Original Log Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to configure my Aws Cloudformation Template such as I would get AWS lambda's Log in A custom Log group along with functions's orginal Log group
sample template

```
    test:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
            Role: arn:aws:iam::434340133258:role/lambda-custom-role
            Handler: test.lambda_handler
            Runtime: python3.8
            CodeUri: test.py
            MemorySize: 128
            Timeout: 200
            Layers:
                - !Ref test
                - !Ref test
            Events:
                NonGithubAPIs:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /test/get
                        Method: get
                        RestApiId: 
                            !Ref test
```

I want to modify this template such as I would get logs in both custom Log group and function's Log Group

Comment: Why do you expect such a feature to even exist? Technically you can build something like this but that is FAAAR more work than a simple configuration setting in CF.